# Clean output for xargs

Tags: bash

As part of tunnel script I wan to remove/kill any existing tunnels

So far I managed to get to:

> matt@HY731AA:~$ ps aux | grep "ssh -N
>   lin1tunnels" | grep -v grep | awk
>   '{print $2}' | xargs -0 kill -9 ERROR:
>   garbage process ID "5321 5322 ".

It looks as if the output contains " although removing the xargs does not show ", is there a way to clean up output ready for xargs. Or maybe someone knows a better way to accomplish the above

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**:

Use [`pkill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill):

```
 pkill -9 -f "ssh -N lin1tunnels"
```

Avoid  sending `SIGKILL` signal to the specified process or process group.  Read the [Useless Use of Kill -9](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#uuk9letter)

Comment: Doesnt seem to work process still exists with both -9 and none

Comment: You need to add `-f` to search the full command with arguments, not just the command name.

Comment: @glenn: yes. i missed that one.+1.

Answer (score 4):

@John's suggestion of pkill is the cleaner way of doing this (if you have it), but just for the record: the problem is that you're using xarg's `-0` flag (which tells it to look for null-delimited values), but sending newline-delimited values.  Also, rather than using a second grep to remove the first one from your results, search for a pattern that won't match itself:

```
ps aux | grep "[s]sh -N lin1tunnels" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```